# How can we guard against greedy optimization of cross-validated performance when point-wise exclusion of data points is used

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, optimization

A classifier is trained using a data set and its performance is evaluated. Then, the classifier's performance is evaluated again when it is trained using that same data set from which a data point has been deleted.
The removal of points as a driving function for performance optimization would encourage us to throw away all but the most well behaved data (meaning that the generalization to unseen data would likely decrease as the cross-validation performance is increased).

How can we guard against greedy optimizations on the CV performance?